# Functions/Truth values

Tags: python, boolean

I am new to functions and am confused on creating a specific function that given three boolean values, returns true if at least two are true. The function I have works when I call the function in the interpreter if I explicitly write in the interpreter like this after running the program(I checked all six combinations):

```py
>>> function(True,False,True)
True
```

But I was thinking I should be able to just type function (b1,b2,b3) after inputting values for those variables. For any inputs for those variables, function (b1,b2,b3) returns False.

```py
b1 = input("enter True or False: ")
b2 = input("enter True or False: ")
b3 = input("enter True or False: ")
def function(b1,b2,b3):
    if b1 is True and b2 is True:
        return True
    if b2 is True and b3 is True:
        return True
    if b1 is True and b3 is True:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: You are probably taking in strings, not booleans. I'm not a python guy so not 100% sure. Look at the documentation for `input()` to see what it returns

Comment: What should happen if you get three Trues?

Comment: Three Trues has at least two Trues so we need to return True.

Comment: If you are using python3 `input` will never return a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using Python 2 (which I doubt), `input` returns a string. Hence you will **always** get `False`.

You have to convert the input to `boolean`. However, this is not as trivial as it seems.

`bool('False')` is the boolean `True`, since all non-empty strings are considered to be `True`.

A workaround will be to explicitly check the input:

```
def get_bool_from_stdin():
    inp = input()
    if inp == 'True':
        return True
    if inp == 'False':
        return False
    raise TypeError('input True or False')
```

Then your function will work as expected:

```
def get_bool_from_stdin():
    inp = input()
    if inp == 'True':
        return True
    if inp == 'False':
        return False
    raise TypeError('input True or False')

b1 = get_bool_from_stdin()
b2 = get_bool_from_stdin()
b3 = get_bool_from_stdin()


def function(b1,b2,b3):
    if b1 == True and b2 == True:
        return True
    if b2 == True and b3 == True:
        return True
    if b1 == True and b3 == True:
        return True
    return False


print(function(b1, b2, b3))
```

Executing:

```
>> True
>> False
>> True
True
```

If all you are really after is verifying that `function` receives at least 2 `True` values you can use `sum` (and use `*args` so it works with arbitrary number of arguments) because Python's boolean is a subclass of `int`:

```
def function(*args):
    return sum(args) >= 2
```

Comment: OP, also consider using `ast.literal_eval()` to get the literal value of input, if you don't want such an explicit solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to define such function. Since you want to return `True` if any two are `True`, this is equivalent to checking is the boolean sum is more than 1.

P.S: As for the input problem, the keyboard input is of type string, so in your case, it would mean checking if statements for "True" or "true".

```
b1 = True
b2 = True
b3 = False

def function(b1,b2,b3):
    return (sum([b1, b2, b3])>1)
    # return (sum(1 for b in [b1, b2, b3] if b)>1)  # Alternative

function(b1, b2, b3)
# True
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but this doesn't solve the issue with the OPs post. It's not their function definition but rather it's their inputs that are causing issues with their function

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe : I appreciate your comment. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The function `input` always returns a *string* of what was entered. If you enter `True`, you are actually getting back the string `'True'`, not the boolean.

You could check the user input and convert the value:

```
b1 = input('Enter True or False: ')
if b1.lower() == 'true':
    b1 = True
else:
    b1 = False
# ...repeat for each input ...
```

In a one-liner you could shorten it:

```
b1 = (True if input('Enter True or False: ').lower() == 'true'
      else False)
```

It is also better to use `b1 is True` rather than `b1 == True`.

Comment: Alright, I changed to == since I wasn't sure if that's what was causing problems. Why is this better?

Comment: `==` causes the underlying `__eq__` method of the object being compared to be called. This method could still return True even when the compared object isn’t the singleton `True`. `is`, on the other hand, compares the _identity_ of the object to `True` and will _only_ return True if the objects are the same. In most cases this doesn’t make any difference, but programs including classes may cause problems when a custom class overrides the `__eq__` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually sum boolean values in Python, so you can check if at least `n` number of inputs are true. This allows a variable number of inputs, but the first input is the number of which must be `True`

```py
def check_n_true(n, *args):
    return sum(args) >= n

check_n_true(2, True, True, False) # True
check_n_true(3, True, True, False) # False
check_n_true(1, True, True, False) # True
```

Comment: The problem OP is having is because they use `input` incorrectly, not due to the implementation of `function`

Answer (score -1):

How about the following?

```
from itertools import combinations
from typing import List

def twotrues(values: List) -> bool:
    return any({all(c) for c in combinations(values, 2)})
```

What it does is to make all possible combinations of two elements from the values-list, check if there are any where both are True and then return that result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem OP is having is because they use `input` incorrectly, not due to the implementation of `function`

Comment: that is true, I agree

Answer (score -2):

The problem is `input` function returns a string. You have to cast it to a boolean value, for example like this:

```
def get_boolean():
    return bool(input("enter True or False: "))

b1 = get_boolean()
b2 = get_boolean()
b3 = get_boolean()
```

Edit, correction:

```
def get_boolean():
    try:
        return {'True': True, 'False': False}[input()]
    except KeyError:
        raise RuntimeError("Not a boolean value")
```

Comment: What is the output of `bool('False')`?

Comment: Ah, right. I was to hasty. Still, the problem lies in parsing of the input.